# Twitter callback redirects to IP address instead of domain

Tags: twitter

I have integrated Twitter API with my web-app. It works nice on dev environment, but on production the call back doesn't use the domain name which I've specified for the callback, instead of it redirect goes to IP address of the production.

In the Twitter Application Management app, on Settings tab I entered values:

Website:      http://mysite.co.uk
Callback URL: https://mysite.co.uk/some/path

What can be a reason of this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not in Twitter, but in environments properties.

Comment: Which ones would be nice to add.